# Hiding Link In SharePoint Quicklaunch Based On Permissions

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, quicklaunch

I am trying to figure out a way to hide a specific link from the Quicklaunch navigation bar on one of my sites in SharePoint 2013 and am having some trouble.  Basically I am trying to make it so that a link is only visible to users within a specific group and any other users that are not part of this group will not see the Quicklaunch link.  I have been reading up on how to implement this via css and javascript within the default master page but do not seem to be having any luck.  I was using SPServices to get the group membership for the currently logged in user and based on there membership either hiding or showing the specific Quicklaunch item. I implemented this code into the master page and  I though I had it working, however upon navigating to a different page, list, or library within the site the given link reappears.  I do not know if I am doing something wrong but as a last resort I have come here for answers.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Bellow is a screenshot to get a better understanding of what it is I am trying to do...

[image: What I am trying to accomplish]

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use [Audience Targeting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293?CorrelationId=b09bbebd-b941-4aab-8806-0259f5d6fef5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for this link?

Comment: I cannot seem to find that option on SharePoint 2013 Foundation.  I am not sure if I am overlooking it or if I need a specific feature activated.

Comment: Apparently, that feature is not available for SharePoint 2013 Foundation https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/713e54d0-dba0-4572-b51f-63a5b0c9aa34/sharepoint-foundation-audience-targeting?forum=sharepointadminprevious.

Comment: Whomp whomp. Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Security trimming should be automatic for the quick launch. Users not being able to see the list, should not see the quicklaunch entry. One thing i experienced in the past is that the security trimming does not work if your quick launch URL looks like this

```
https://url/sites/sc/Lists/internallistname
```

but will work if you include the aspx-page

```
https://url/sites/sc/Lists/internallistname/AllItems.aspx
```

Don't know about foundation but it's worth a try...